# JQuery & CSS - css() is not working

Tags: jquery, css

How would I set something with `css()` the following code? I tried but it doesn't work!

I looked for a way to do that but still couldn't find it! Not even here: **http://api.jquery.com/css/**

**NOT working**

```
$('#MyClass123').css('content:url','("image.jpg")');
$('#MyClass123').css('content','url("image.jpg")');
$('#MyClass123').css('content:url("image.jpg")');
```

**Working**

```
<style>
.MyClass123{
    content:url("image.jpg");
}
</style>

<img class="MyClass123"/>
```

Comment: It's not just a coincidence that jQuery uses [extended] CSS selectors .. so how does the "NOT working" and "Working" differ?

Comment: In any case, take the time to apply troubleshooting - "isn't working" isn't a good problem description. A little testing would show that `$(..)` selects 0 elements .. well, good, so then why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the second one in NOT working would be correct way to do it. however, it's not working because you're selecting an ID called MyClass123, when you should be selecting a class:

```
$('.MyClass123').css('content','url("image.jpg")');
```

Comment: @kennypu Oh my.. HAHAHAHA.. I can't believe I was missing that! Thank you!

Comment: See my below answer. You should use $('img.MyClass123') instead.

Answer (score 1):

Change `#` to `.`

Your select statement is looking for an id not a class.

When I get on my pc kater ill give u more info, msbe zomeone will be kind enough to update this answer

jQuery select statements should look exactly like their css counterpart

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$('img.MyClass123')` instead. `$('#MyClass123')` selects an element with the **id** MyClass1234, e.g. `<img id="MyClass123" />`.

Basically every selector that starts with a hash (#) indicates that you're looking for an id. Selectors with dots (.) indicate that you're looking for classes. The difference between ids and classes is that several elements can have the same class but only one element can carry a distinct id at the same time.

In line with that you could also use the selector `$('.MyClass123')`. It would find ALL elements with the class MyClass123 however. As such it might return a different element than the image you're looking for. For example `<a href="#" class="MyClass123">` could be matched. Using the img component before the dot is more distinct.

Check: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp